# Unchecking options in activity history in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to find how to uncheck the options in Activity history in privacy settings. I need to do it with a script preferably in powershell. I know that it is possible to block in group policy, but the end result is blocking, not unchecking. In the picture how it should look like [Activity history with unchecking 2 options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTczN.png)

Answer (score 0):

the related registry key is:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System

Property: PublishUserActivities
Value: 0 = disable, 1 = enable
```

But the result is simliar like to configure this setting by using GPO.